# How should I set up the a second website in relationship to my first website for maximum SEO benefits?

Tags: seo, multiple-domains

I'll try to make this simple and also explain why I"m doing this.

I own **website A**, which stocks candles mostly for retail and church use. I now have the opportunity to become a reseller for church products under a different name.

For simplicity's sake I **was** going to add those products to **site A**. Now I realize that my demographics are not very compatible, and  need to set up a second website for church products - **site B**.

I hate to start from SEO scratch! My question. Is there a way to set up the second site side by side on the same hosting service so that Google sees it as ONE site but the end user of each site would not see the other one.

To clarify.

**Wordpress site A** -- original domain sharing link juice and reputation with
**Wordpress site B** -- residing on same hosting service but with new domain pointing at it?

The websites will not share keywords, design, content or customers, they will be different from each other in almost every way.

I'm open to ANY suggestions on how to do this.

Comment: Awesome thanks guys, this really helps out. I'll go ahead and set up a brand new domain with links just pointing from the old site to the new one!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to set up the second site side by side on the same hosting service so that Google sees it as ONE site but the end user of each site would not see the other one.

You might be able to pull it off with subdomains but that's probably not separate enough given your description.  Any other tricks to show Google one thing and the users another gets into cloaking territory and I don't think you will like where you will end up if you try it.  You would be better off just starting the second site's SEO from scratch and cross-linking the sites extensively for discoverability and link-juicing.  I doubt you would have to wait very long to see results.

You might even consider a third approach which would be to combine stores from each of the sites as one unified cart.  That way the WordPress sites becomes nothing but marketing arms but customers would be able to have a unified shopping experience and add product from either line to a single cart and checkout that way.  You could subdomain the store only (store.wordpressA.com; store.wordpressB.com) and have that serve as the common thread.

Comment: I would add that reputation is just links between websites so having many links between both sites will be enough. Only, remember that if page A on site I links to page B on site II and vice versa, then the juice gets lost. In other words, you want the existing site to have links to the new site, and not very much the other. At least at the start.

Comment: Awesome thanks so guys, this really helps out. I'll go ahead and set up a brand new domain with links just pointing from the old site to the new one! Again really appreciate you guys taking the time to answer this.